# Javascript function error (function not defined)

Tags: javascript, function, dev-to-production

I wrote a javascript function (already tested it and it works) on a file in a development server and it works just fine, I uploaded the file to the production server and when I test it I get the following error:

Opera Dragonfly says:

```
Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'App.system.ManageProductLines' to object
```

Firebug says:

```
App.system.ManageProductLines is undefined
```

The files are exactly the same (I checked with WinMerge and found no differences), the only difference is the server on which they're on.

My development server is the latest version of Xampp on windows and the production server is the latest version of Xampp on OpenSuse.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on??

### Edit:

Suggested by dtryon, here's some example code:

In main.js

```
App.system.ManageProductLines = function()
{
     var init_row = function(row)
     {
          //function to add table row behavior
     }

     var reindex_odd_even_rows = function(table)
     {
           //function to reoder table when row is deleted
     }

 }
```

In index.tpl (Smarty template):

```
{if $product_lines_url}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        App.system.ManageProductLines.init('manage_product_lines');
    </script>
{/if}
```

The if in the smarty template is indeed executing, since the final HTML has the script tage in it, however in dev server the function is found, but in production server it isn't

### Edit 2:

Thanks to Paul Butcher I think I'm getting closer to the answer, I tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    App.system.ManageProductLines.init('manage_product_lines');
});
</script>
```

However it still wouldn't load, then I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
         alert("Start document.ready");

         if(App.system.ManageProductLines.init)
         {
            alert("Method found");
            App.system.ManageProductLines.init('manage_product_lines');
         }
         else
         {
             alert("Method not found");
         }

         alert("End document.ready");
});
```

According to what I wrote I should get the following alerts:

```
"Start document.ready", "Method found" || "Method not found", "End document.ready"
```

The weird thing is I only get "Start document.ready", after that it seems that it just stops executing, both Opera Dragonfly and Firebug show the same error as before.

Comment: Any chance you could post the code that is blowing up?

Comment: I know this is an obvious thing to check but I wonder if your javascript file is cached and you need to clear cache. Also what @dtryon said.

Comment: Right after you load App.system.ManageProductLines, do a `console.log` and see if 1. it really is loaded 2. that section of code actually runs

Comment: @dtryon, I really wanted to post the code, however I can't due to licensing issues, I know that posting code is almost vital but sadly I'm not allowed to.

Comment: @caleb, I did the log and just as I thought the function isn't being run at all

Comment: @JulianCuevas can you create example code that isolates the issue?

Comment: @dtryon Didn't think of that, I've edited the post to include example code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time this line is reached:

```
App.system.ManageProductLines.init('manage_product_lines');
```

There is no certainty that main.js has been loaded or executed.  You need to bind that call to an event that will only occur after all scripts have been loaded.

If you are using one, most javascript libraries offer such an event (e.g. `ready` in jQuery).  If you are not using one, then binding to onload should work.

One possible reason for the difference between the two environments may be network latency or load. This is particularly likely if the development server is localhost.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I tried binding the call to ready, however it still won't start at all, I've edited my original post to include what I did, can you help me??

Comment: Looking in firebug, can you see if any of the objects along that chain are instantiated?  i.e. Do App, App.system, and App.system.ManageProductLines all exist?

Comment: Well, both App and App.system exist, but App.system.ManageProductLines doesn't seem to

Comment: So it sounds like the problem isn't really on the line you give, but on the line where ManageProductLines is assigned, or soemwhere before that.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, the problem is that the server application (activecollab 2), already had a file with the exact same name, which for some reason always held a higher priority that my file, after contacting AC support the only option was to overwrite their file with mine.